# Perl how to add sheet into existing excel file which contains macros and formulas?

Tags: perl, excel

I have a problem with editing a file.
I'm using the module [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet%3a%3aParseExcel%3a%3aSaveParser) from CPAN.
The existing data in the file I want to add a new set of data and save the file as a new.

Unfortunately, the new file will not write a macro or formula.
Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`, I believe.

You should be able to do it with [`Win32::OLE`](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1709/lib/Win32/OLE.pm), which allows you to programmatically control Excel itself.  See [the first example in the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1709/lib/Win32/OLE.pm#EXAMPLES).